# Cauchy matrices with elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: matrices, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, co.combinatorics

$\newcommand{\vx}{\mathbf{x}}$
Let $e_k(\vx)$ denote the [elementary symmetric polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), defined for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$ over a vector $\vx=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ by

\begin{equation*}
  e_k(\vx) := \sum_{1 \le l_1 < l_2 < \cdots < l_k \le n} x_{l_1}x_{l_2}\cdots x_{l_k}.
\end{equation*}

To avoid messy conjugates in what follows, let me limit $x$ to be a real vector.

[**EDIT**]: Changed notation below to highlight that size of $M_k$ is independent of size of the vectors being used to define it.

> **Definition** (GC-matrix) Let $(\vx^1,\ldots,\vx^m)$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that each component $|x^p_j| < 1$ (for $1\le p \le m$, $1\le j \le n$). Denote by $\vx^i \circ \vx^j$ the vector formed by taking elementwise products; also, let $\mathbf{1}$ denote the length $n$ vector of all ones.
>
> Define now the $m\times m$ *Generalized Cauchy (GC) matrix* $M_k$, for $1\le k\le n$, as
>   \begin{equation*}
>    M_k := \left[\frac{1}{e_k(\mathbf{1}-\vx^i\circ \vx^j)}\right]_{i,j=1}^m.
> \end{equation*}

**Example** For $e_1(\vx)=\sum_lx_l$, the GC matrix above essentially (up to scaling) boils down to a standard [Cauchy matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix), of the form
\begin{equation*}
   \left[\frac{1}{1-\lambda_i\lambda_j}\right],
\end{equation*}
for suitable scalars $\lambda_i$; while for $e_n(\vx)=\prod_l x_l$, the GC matrix reduces to a Hadamard product of ordinary Cauchy matrices.

> **Question.**   The above example shows that $M_1$ and $M_n$ are positive semidefinite (since the involved Cauchy matrices are). So my question is there a slick representation for $e_k$ that I could use to conclude positive semidefiniteness of $M_k$?

---

**PS:** I suspect the answer follows immediately from well-known (in the correct circles) results; but I need some MO help here to put me rapidly in the correct direction!

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has seems to have a negative answer (as proved to me very recently by one of the mathematicians with whom I discussed it; will update this question once I get a chance.)